# SPSS: comparing 2 variables in 3 populations

Tags: multiple-regression, t-test, spss, sample

I have 2 variables, both percentages, that I want to compare across 3 samples. I want to see if the first percentage differs significantly from the second percentage, for each sample. Originally, I thought I'd split file by sample, then run a t-test. But I'm getting confusing results.

Would really welcome step-by-step and simple advice on what analyses you'd run for this scenario.

Comment: I think some more details about what your data look like and what is confusing about the results you're seeing would be helpful to anyone trying to answer.

Comment: I'm looking at three populations. They were asked to predict a percentage for one question and a percentage for another question. I thought both percentages would be similar, but they're looking very different. Which is really interesting. So I want to be able to statistically look at if they are statistically significantly different from one another. When I ran the t-test, two of the samples listed one factor, and one of the samples listed both factors. I don't know why, and I can't understand what went wrong in my input...